# Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8082, App not installing in react-native, gradle build failed

Tags: react-native, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem
  might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For
  example, an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the User
  Manual chapter on the daemon at
  https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Process
  command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\java.exe
  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
  java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
  java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
  java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Nagaraj.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.9-all\dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs\gradle-6.9\lib\gradle-launcher-6.9.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.9 Please read the
  following process output to find out more:

Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.